# Ocropus 0.44 Usage

Tags: linux, debian

I believe I have installed OCRopus successfully, strangely I can't find any usage instructions anywhere, been looking for about an hour, perhaps I'm crazy...

How do I use OCRopus?

I want it to OCR a PNG file into an HTML file saving the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.ralree.com/2010/05/17/how-to-use-ocropus-to-create-html-book-scan-output/) link might help you.

Excerpt:

> go to your directory of appropriately named book page scan images
>   (tiff or png). When you type ls, you should see the pages list in
>   order! Then, try:
>
> ocropus book2pages out image*
>
> This grooms the pages for OCR. Next, let’s make the page objects, and
>   eventually the book:
>
> ocropus pages2lines out
>
> ocropus lines2fsts out/
>
> ocropus fsts2text out/
>
> ocropus buildhtml out/ > book.html
>
> That should create you a nice book html file, in the hOCR format.

Also there are many tutorials on how to use ocropus.

Comment: OK. Thank you. It seems that the installation wasn't successful afterall, which would explain my confusion. I managed to install OCRFeeder, so I'm trying that out now.